# passing a parameter from input text through onClick on reactjs

Tags: reactjs

im trying to pass a string to a function using `onClick` method, here is my code :

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const todos = [
{id: 1, nama: 'belajar', status: 'selesai'},
{id: 2, nama: 'makan', status: 'belum selesai'}
]

export class MyTodos extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
  }
}

function sayHello(name) {
  alert(`hello, ${this.name}`);
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Navbar">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark rounded-pill col-sm-8">  
          <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-6 rounded-pill" name="aktivitas"></input>
          <button className="btn form-control form-control-sm col-sm-4 bg-light rounded-pill" onClick={() => sayHello(this.aktivitas)}>
            Tambah
          </button>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <br></br><br></br>
      <div className="Kartu card">
        <ul className="list-group list-group-flush"> 
              {todos.map(todos => <li className="list-group-item">{todos.nama} : {todos.status}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}




export default App;
```

the expected output is, when i type something inside the `input field` it will give me an alert that says `Hello, <inputted string>` For example if i type `name` inside the `input field` it will gave me `hello, name`

i guess it have something to do with binding something, i tried to bind it bit it gave me this error :
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'aktivitas' of undefined`

thanks before, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<button className="btn form-control form-control-sm col-sm-4 bg-light rounded-pill" onClick={(e) => {
     this.sayHello(e, this.aktivitas)
}}>Tambah</button>
```

The function body should be:

```
sayHello = (event, aktivitas) => {
     console.log(aktivitas);
};
```

Comment: i still got the same error, here is the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'sayHello' of undefined`

Comment: @LuthfiMusafa, I have updated my answer. as you are using class component so we have to use arrow function. Please check sayHello function

Answer (score 0):

Try code bellow.

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const todos = [
{id: 1, nama: 'belajar', status: 'selesai'},
{id: 2, nama: 'makan', status: 'belum selesai'}
]

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const handleOnChange = React.useCallback((event) => {
    const { target: { value } } = event;
    
    setName(value);
  }, []);

  const sayHello = React.useCallback(() => {
    alert(`hello, ${name}`);
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Navbar">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark rounded-pill col-sm-8">  
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-6 rounded-pill"
            name="aktivitas"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
          />
          <button
            className="btn form-control form-control-sm col-sm-4 bg-light rounded-pill"
            onClick={sayHello}
          >
            Tambah
          </button>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <br></br><br></br>
      <div className="Kartu card">
        <ul className="list-group list-group-flush"> 
              {todos.map(todos => <li className="list-group-item">{todos.nama} : {todos.status}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, you need `onChange` on your input tag:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const todos = [
{id: 1, nama: 'belajar', status: 'selesai'},
{id: 2, nama: 'makan', status: 'belum selesai'}
]

class MyTodos extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      aktivitas: '',
    };

    this.sayHello = this.sayHello.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }


    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({ aktivitas: e.target.value });
    }

    sayHello(){
        console.log(this.state.aktivitas);
    }


    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="Navbar">
            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark rounded-pill col-sm-8">  
              <input type="text" className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-6 rounded-pill" name="aktivitas" onChange={ this.handleChange }></input>
              <button className="btn form-control form-control-sm col-sm-4 bg-light rounded-pill" onClick={ this.sayHello }>Tambah</button>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <br></br><br></br>
          <div className="Kartu card">
            <ul className="list-group list-group-flush"> 
                  {todos.map(todos => <li className="list-group-item">{todos.nama} : {todos.status}</li>)}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

}



export default MyTodos;
```